# How can I insert a page break using Find/Replace dialog in Word 2007?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, find-and-replace

I'm trying to replace "----------" with a new page or a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

I pasted "CTRL+ENTER" into the "Replace With:" field in Microsoft Word 2007, hoping that when I clicked "Replace All" I'd have new pages where I had my dashes...

It didn't work.

Something is telling me that there is a much easier (working) way.  **What is it**?
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace with `^m`. That is the code for what you want to do.